# Oracle subquery syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, subquery

```
select count (time) 
from passage 
where time between 500 and 620 **ON**  
(select Hours||''||Minutes as time                  
from passage);
```

I am not sure want I need to put instead of the ON.

I am trying to count the number of time a bus is passing during an interval.

thank you!

Comment: Is this your homework? Is subquery a requirement?

Comment: Yes it's my homework. Subquery is not a requirement but i don't know how to do it without a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON` is for joining two tables, it's not part of the `WHERE` clause:

I am not entirely sure what 500 and 620 represent, but you shouldn't compare numbers with strings.

I *think* you are after something like this:

```
select count (time) 
from passage 
where hours * 60 + minutes between 500 and 620
```

Comment: this was my subquery, now that it's working, can you help me with the entire query?